# BLE Read the response after executing write

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a bluetooth feature in Ionic. I have to write certain bytes over bluetooth and read the response when done. Following id the write code in typescript:

```
let bufferArray = [1,5,3,9,4,1];
for (var a = 0; a < bufferArray.length; a++) {
  this.ble.write(this.peripheral.id
                  , "0x0018" 
                  , "wbi"
                  , new Uint8Array([bufferArray[a]]).buffer
                ).then(
    (buffer) => {

    }
  )
}
```

When I see the receiving device log, the log displays the bytes received, accepted and processed. Now, my issue is that when this is done, I have to read the response. I apologize if I am not making sense because I have not work in bluetooth before and I am very confused.

Thank You for reading my post.

Comment: what about a well placed `read()`? from docs `read(deviceId, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID)` Im just htinking out loud im not too familiar with what you are doing

Comment: Thanks, I tried read but still having issue. I am going to keep trying until I find something.